# Set a before action to all member routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncontroller

Playing around with Rails 4, I noticed that it defines a `before_action` filter `set_[model]`, that is called for the actions `show`, `edit`, `update` and `destroy`.

It is in fact very useful, but I don't see much sense in not having it to all member actions. After all, if you are using a member action, you want to act on that member, thus you need to recover it from database at some point.

Note that by member actions, I also means the ones configured on `routes.rb` in the `members` block.

Is there a straight-forward way to do this, without list all member actions on the `before_action` filter?

**Edit:** To clarify, the whole point is use some rails magic to get all member routes and generate the array that would be pass in the `:only`. So I can do something like

```
before_action set_model only: all_member_routes
```

where `all_member_routes` is a piece of code that returns all member routes for my model.

Or even better,

```
before_action set_model, only_member_actions: true
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `show`, `edit`, `update`, `destroy` actions are precisely all member actions. They are the only ones that require to find the model.

If you have your own member action, then you'll have to add it to the list yourself.

```
before_action :set_item, only: [:edit, ..., :my_member_action]
```

Or, you can use the `:except` option to exclude all the collection actions that do not need it:

```
before_action :set_item, except: [:index, :create]
```

This way, if you add other member actions, you wont have to change anything.
Personally, I prefer to be explicit and use `:only`.

I'm pretty sure there is no easier way to do it, you can't detect all member actions automatically.

---

**edit**:

I really don't think you should do that but...

You can access the name of your controller with the `controller_name` method.

Getting the routes related to the controller:

```
routes = Rails.application.routes.routes.select { |r| r.defaults[:controller] == controller_name }
```

Then, I think the best way to see if a route is a member route is that the `@parts` array includes `:id`. Maybe you can find a more robust way.

So I would do:

```
routes.select { |r| r.parts.include?(:id) }.map { |r| r.defaults[:action] }.map &:to_sym
```

That would give you: `[:show, :preview, :my_challenges]` for

```
 resources :users, only: [:index, :show], controller: 'accounts/users' do
   member do
     get :preview
     get :my_challenges
   end
 end
```

---

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base 

    def member_routes
        Rails.application.routes.routes
            .select { |r| r.defaults[:controller] == controller_name && r.parts.include?(:id) }
            .map { |r| r.defaults[:action] }
            .map(&:to_sym)
    end

end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
    before_action set_model, only: member_routes
end
```

Comment: You can define extra member actions on your routes.rb, right? So, I want to include those as well.

Comment: Yep, so as I said, you only have 2 choices, add your `my_member_action ` action to the list, or use `:except`, that's it.

Comment: the whole point is use some rails magic to get all member routes and generate the list for me :-)

Comment: I updated my answer, it's not tested, except in the console, but that kinda does what you want (= return an array of member action names that you can use in your `all_member_routes` method). I really don't think you should do that, but it's up to you ;)

Comment: can you explain why I shouldn't do that? If it is a member action, it is not natural to get that member to do an action? What is the drawback?

Comment: It's relying on internals of Rails, it's not particularly efficient, it's better to be explicit in this case in my opinion. Do you have such a huge number of member methods that you really need that? I would tend to agree raviolicode, you probably should split your code into different controllers, if you can.

Answer (score 4):

If you ask for a `before_action` without `:only` or `:except` options, it will apply to all member actions:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :require_login

  private

  def require_login
    unless logged_in?
      flash[:error] = "You must be logged in to access this section"
      redirect_to new_login_url # halts request cycle
    end
  end
end
```

In this particular case, it will require login from all actions on **all controllers**, since controllers will inherit from ApplicationController.

You can skip a `before_action` if you need it (for example, you need to skip `require_login` if you want to `login` into the system or `sign up`) like this:

```
class LoginsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :require_login, only: [:new, :create]
end
```

Source: [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html)

---

So, in your particular case:

You could have one usual UserController:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end


  ...
  /* you define here `index`, `create`, `update`, ... */
  def destroy
    ...
  end
end
```

And you could have a separate controller with all your member actions:

```
class UserCustomController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_model

  def profile
    ...
  end

  def preview
  end   

  def custom_member_action
  end

  ...
  /* all your member actions */
end
```

This would be actually better than having a single controller with lots of methods.

Comment: The idea of my question is add a new member route on my routes.rb and don't need to add nothing on any array, don't matter if `only` or `except` array.

Comment: Do you mean about `resources :user` to generate routes for the User model for example?

Comment: like `resources :user do member do get :profile done done` - this is a custom member route. More info on [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions)

Comment: fotanus, I'm not sure if this what you're looking for, but since you should try to stick to REST actions for controllers in Rails, and not having a lot of actions in the same controller... this could give you what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This could work, except that I prefer to list the controllers manually. Note that adding new RESTful actions on the same controller is not something bad, neither the software stop from being RESTful from adding some more actions.

Comment: Sorry, I mean list **actions** manualy - on a `only` or `except` parameter.

Comment: What I mean, is that by having a lot of controller actions besides the RESTful ones, you're feeling the pain of writing all the methods names, there could be a smell. Check this post by [Ryan Bates on Multiple Scopes in Controller](http://archive.railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=737)

Comment: This was just something that come with my mind, not that I'm really having a lot of trouble doing it. Thanks anyway :-)

Comment: My `before_action` is getting called on custom `collection` methods (ex. search) too even though I've explicitly passed the `only: [:new, :create]` option. It doesn't get called on `index` method but is being called on `search` method.